# JavaScript For Loop Not Returning Expected String

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to pull the names of purchased products into an advertising pixel for reporting purposes. An example is in the below image:

[image]

I'm trying to use the below function to loop through the object and return only the names, comma separated, as a string within a single variable. i'm using the below script:

```
function products() {
    var items = _rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items;
    var product = "";
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        product += product + _rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items[i].name + ",";
        i++;
    }
console.log(product);
}
products();
```

but it's only logging the first product like so: Purity Organic CBD Sleep Tea - Chamomille 15mg 18 Count,

Any help on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You already have an `i++` at the top of the for loop, you don't need another at the bottom!

Comment: Also `product += product + _rsq...` is redundant. Either do `product = product + _rsq...` or `product += _rsq...`, but you probably don't want to do both

Comment: Please provide data as text,, not as a picture of text. In this case, you can likely use `console.log(JSON.stringify(_rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items, null, 2))` to produce a decent view of what's in the array, copy, and paste it into the question. See [ask] for more tips on how to write good questions.

Comment: The extra `i++` means that you're hitting the end condition faster (i.e. `i >= items.length`).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your code to work, simply remove the extra `i++` and change the `+=` line slightly, like this:

```js
function products() {
    var items = _rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items;
    var product = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        product +=
            _rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items[i].name + ',';
    }
    console.log(product);
}
products();
```

However, I would suggest using one of these three alternatives to for loops. If you use methods like these, you will altogether avoid the issue of accidentally writing `i++` twice, and your code will be more readable in general.

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Sleep',
        price: 24.99,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Revive',
        price: 24.99,
    },
];

const productsUsingReduce = () => {
    return items.slice(1).reduce((result, item) => {
        return `${result}, ${item.name}`;
    }, items[0].name);
};

const productsUsingFor = () => {
    let result = items[0].name;
    items.slice(1).forEach((item) => {
        result += `, ${item.name}`;
    });
    return result;
};

const productsUsingJoin = () => {
    return items
        .map((item) => {
            return item.name;
        })
        .join(', ');
};

console.log(productsUsingReduce());
console.log(productsUsingFor());
console.log(productsUsingJoin());
```

The only* reason I have found where you actually need a for loop is if you are using `await` to run multiple asynchronous calls in a specific order.

**If you are forced to use old version(s) of javascript/node for some strange reason, then you may end up having to use for loops.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with standard for loops!

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I edited my answer to provide a working solution to the question, while still providing extra advice.

Comment: there's not, but this seems simpler to me: `items.map((i)=>{return i.name})`

Comment: I stand by my comment. The fact is, *most* people do not repeat the post-increment operation. I don't think any of the alternatives you've shown are "more readable" (especially with the confusing and unneeded `slice`) than an indexed for loop, except the `map` + `join` (which I would do as `items.map(item => item.name).join(', ')`).

Comment: You are correct that most people do not repeat the `i++`. Readability is subjective so we don't need to discuss it more here. And your `map`+`join` is the same as mine, so it looks like we agree on that.

Comment: Also, @Heretic Monkey how would you suggest producing the desired output without using `slice`? Simply starting at the first element and going through the whole list will lead to an extraneous leading or trailing comma. Is there a better way around this (besides `join`)?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland the question specified "as a string within a single variable." Your suggestion produces an array.

Comment: It would.  It was also not posted as an answer to the question, just an observation that I think map is cleaner than a loop.

Comment: And why would you want to avoid the join anyway? That's what it's for. To avoid it you used slice() and template literals and items[0].name.

Comment: Both `reduce` and `forEach` take a function that is provided the index of the item being being sent. Simply check if that is 0; if not, prepend a `,`.

Comment: That's what I thought :/

Answer (score 0):

When you do `x += 2`, it is the same as if you did `x = x + 2`, so the second `product` in `product += product` has to be removed in order to get the correct result.

You can shorten the `_rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items` to just `items`, because you declared it before the for-loop as `items` and you never changed it.

Also, you added extra `i++`, which is not necessary, because you already increment `i` in the for-loop, specifically at the end of this line: `for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++)`.

This should work:

```
function products() {
    var items = _rsq.executor.sentWave.order_properties.order_items;
    var product = "";

    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        product += items[i].name + ",";
    }

    console.log(product);
}

products();
```